# SQLite delete specific row not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a SQLite table with below command in my app.

```
 db.execSQL("Create table if not exists mytab(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement not null,deviceid int,leftsof Real,rightsof Real)");
```

I have around 30000 rows in this table now and I am transferring data to server. Data is inserting to server table smoothly but on every insertion I want to delete specific SQLite table row being inserted.

Here is code for that.

```
     try {


                        for (int i = 0; i < databaseWorking.getlati().size(); i++) {
                            System.out.println("Local DB Size " + databaseWorking.getlati().size());

//code for insertion
                            if (response == 200) {

                                databaseWorking.deleterow(i);
                            }
                        }
```

Code for deleting row

```
  void deleterow(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Delete from mytab Where Id=" + id ;
                   sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
    }
```

But rows are not deleted though delete method is being called and there is no error. Everytime I m getting same size of database.

can someone guide ?

Comment: Apparently, there are no rows with `Id` value that match those `i`s.

Comment: understand, I just short the real words here for representative purpose, actually they are leftsof and rightsof.

Comment: I edited and sorry for that.

Comment: @CL (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement  is not Id column which can be compared? and if not then how can I delete row,

Comment: How do you know which rows have been sent to the server? Or is it all of them?

Comment: @CL, strange u were throwing questions instead of helping, anyway, got issue as I was passing loop value as id to check and delete, instead I should get row value from table and then pass it. It is deleting rows now Finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly for the first iteration there will be no deletion as **i** (the for loop counter) will be 0 and there will be no row with **Id** being 0 unless you have set the **Id** to 0 specifically. Whether or not subsequent rows will match i is impossible to say with the information given.

I'd suggest retrieving the actual **Id** for example

1) Add a new method to get all the rows to be transferred and deleted (this assumes all);

```
Cursor getRowsToDelete() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase;
    Return db.query("mytab",null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

2) Modify the existing deleterow method to accept a long, to use the `delete` method (this will return the number of rows deleted for each) and return the number of rows deleted.

```
int deleterow(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.delete("mytab",
        "Id=?,
        new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
}
```

3) Instead of the for loop use :-

```
SQliteDatabase databaseWorking;
Cursor csr = databaseWorking.getRowsToDelete();
int initialrowwcount = csr.getCount();
int deletecount = 0;
while (csr.moveToNext()) {
     //....... your insertion code .....
    if (response == 200) {
        if (databaseWorking.deleterow(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("Id"))) < 1) {
            System.out.println(" Row with Id " +
                csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("Id")) + 
                " was not deleted.");
        } else {
            deletecount++;
        }
    }
}
csr.close();
System.out.println("Out of " +
        Integer.toString(initialrowcount) +
        " rows, " +
        integer.toString(deleteccount) +
        " rows were deleted.";
}
```

This retrieves all rows into an SQLite Cursor using the getRowsToDelete method created in step 1. It then loops through the rows using the `moveToNext` method of the Cursor, this will loop through the rows of the Cursor which may be in any order (you can specify the order in the `query` method).

The actual Id is extracted using the Cursor's `getLong` method (there is a getInt method however as rowid's (specifying `Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL` makes the **Id** column an alias for the ROWID column)).

The `getLong` method like all the get????? methods takes the column index(offset, so 0 is the first column) as an argument (Id would very likely be 0). However the `getColumnIndex`, which takes the column name, as a string, as it's argument returns the column index according to the column name (using this is less likely to result in coding the incorrect column index).

`csr.close()` closes/finishes with the cursor.

The above code would be a prime candidate for using an SQLite TRANSACTION. However, for brevity this has not been included. Using a transaction could markedly reduce the time taken.

Comment: thanks mike for sharing different options and helping me in finding solution using ur 3 option

Comment: @Panache my pleasure to help.